# SAPUI5 - AJAX CORS Issue

Tags: ajax, cors, sapui5, asp.net-core-webapi, sap-fiori

I know this is a topic that occures a lot. I have searched the Internet but I could not find a solution for my problem yet:

I am developing an SAPUI5 Fiori app in the SAP Web IDE. The App will be deployed on an internal server within our company network. So the app will only work inside the company network.

Now I have simple ASP.NET Core Web API that is running on a separate server also inside the company network.

When i deploy the app and try to consume the web api via AJAX request, i become the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myserver:5000/api/test' from
>   origin 'https://sap.mycompany.com:44315' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

My Code on the Web API:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "AllowOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://sap.mycompany.com:44315")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowOrigin")));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
    app.UseMvc();

}
```

Controller:

```
// POST: api/test
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> test([FromBody] item)
{
    try
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // throw exception
        return BadRequest("Error");
    }

    return Ok("Success");         
}
```

My Code on the Fiori-Frontend:

Controller:

```
onTestButtonPress: async function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myserver:5000/api/test",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: $.param({
            "Firstname":"John",
            "Lastname":"Rambo"
        }),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

I Have tried anything but I still receive the CORS error in Google Chrome. I also startet Google Chrome with diabled web-security:

> chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If your SAPUI5 app runs on SAP Cloud Platform, you should define your REST API as a Destination and then consume that destination from your app.

If it runs on SAP Gateway (or any other web server you have control of), you may configure your server to respond with header like `‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ : ‘http://myserver:5000/api/test’`

Comment: While developing it runs on SAP Cloud Platform and since my Web API is'nt reachable from outside of the company network, it is impossible to test it. I can only test it when i deploy the app on the SAP Gateway which is inside our company network.

Answer (score 0):

Now after a few hours struggling, finally it works. I have changed my code on the API as following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "AllowOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://sap.mycompany.com:44315")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowOrigin")));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
    app.UseMvc();

}
```

Also I have forgot to add the ContentType in my Ajax-Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myserver:5000/api/test",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: $.param({
        "Firstname":"John",
        "Lastname":"Rambo"
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly has changed? It's not clear at the first glance.

Comment: Please accept your answer (if possible after adding an explanation what exactly helped to solve) to let others know that the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. For me help this `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir` as parameter for google chrome

Comment: Thanks but as I already mentioned above, this did not solve my problem

Comment: as i said.. with --disable-web-security --disable-gpu it does not work.. try it like i write above

Comment: It does not matter if you add --user-data-dir or not, this is only to save the settings on the corresponding user-data directory.

Comment: thats why chrome it suggest if you dont want you dont have to. Is like i said.. with version 49 its with --user-data-dir